# Does SAS use data structures like Java

Tags: java, data-structures, sas

Java has the concept of data structures. Each data structure has its own advantages and disadvantages. In SAS, all data always goes into a 'data' step?

What java Collection does the 'data' in SAS compare to? Is it an Array, a List? Seems more like a Hashmap?

Is it even fair to draw this comparison?

Comment: SAS internally keeps data with key / value pairs.  The Java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class would be the closest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS data can be likened to a tables in any typical RDBMS.  So probably a two dimensional array would be the fairest comparison.  ie.  a table structure.

These structures can be operated on by all sorts of procedures (e.g. `proc sort`, `proc sql`, etc.) or the `data` step.

It's definitely not a hashmap as data in SAS does not require a unique key (as implemented by hashmaps).

If you wanted a different data structure such as a graph structure containing nodes, and edges, etc. then SAS does not really provide a mechanism to represent them.

Comment: That is funny, considering data strcutures and algorithms are such a base concept in so many other languages.

Comment: Isn't a collection of a specific class more inline with a table structure than a two-dimensional array? I feel that a collection of a class would be much more useful. Perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: @Victor a table is a data structure too. But SAS does not aim to be a general purpose programming language. Specializing means being better at certain things (table-ish data) but sacrificing others that you (think you) don't need to support (graphs). Java isn't great for either but you can implement both with some work (neo4j is a java written graph database for example that won't do good with tables I guess)

Comment: @Psychrom A collection of arrays perhaps =).  A collection of classes, not so much.  What if the class represented a data structure that can't be mapped to a 1-dimensional array (ie. a row).  Then a collection of classes would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/SASRead_os.htm says

> You can think of a data set as a two-dimensional table

which IMO means that nothing directly comparable comes with standard Java.
You can build similar (functionally equivalent) data structures with lists of lists or other collection of collection compositions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a direct comparison to a Java collection type, but articles I've seen loosely correlate it to an array.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003252712.htm

> Only one-dimensional array parameters are supported. However, it is
>   possible to pass multidimensional array arguments by taking advantage
>   of the fact that the arrays are passed in row-major order. You must
>   handle the dimensional indexing manually in the Java code--that is,
>   you must declare a one-dimensional array parameter and index to the
>   subarrays accordingly.